# printing random numbers when printing a variable with printf()

Tags: java, object

I'm trying just to print a simple thing that says : `Hola hi hello`, but for some reason it is printing what I want but I get some numbers on my output

Sorry if its an easy thing to find or fix but I'm just starting with java so I'm a complete noob.

My files look like:

**Example.java**

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args){

            Hola ho = new Hola("hola");

            System.out.printf("%s hi hello", ho);
    }
}
```

**Hola.java**

```
class Hola {
    public String name;

    public Hola(String name){
        this.name = name;

    }
}
```

**Output: Hola@7852e922 hi hello%**

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method of your `Hola` class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `ho.name`:

```
System.out.printf("%s hi hello", ho.name);
```

because `ho` will print the object reference and not the name.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my issue :) so do you know what those numbers are? are they just the memory that the variable holds ?

Comment: @FidelCastro this question already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4 read this and you will understand more :)

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `toString()` method of your `Hola` class:

```
class Hola {
    public String name;

    public Hola(String name){
        this.name = name;

    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a better practice or has a better performance than doing this: System.out.printf("%s hi hello", ho.name);

Comment: It really depends on why and how you are using your `class`. If it makes sense to `return` the `name` in the `toString()` method of the `class` then I would do it the way I have it...At the very least you should probably make your variable private and make a `getter` and `setter` for it unless you have a specific reason for making it `public`.